# How to put horizontal dropdown menu bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've faced a problem putting a horizontal sub menu bar. Basically, I can do vertical dropdown menubar, But I haven't any idea how to make horizontal dropdown menu bar. This is what I can:
http://jsfiddle.net/eSxT9

But I need this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/idx2r5bkbuzd1t0/horizonatl-sub-menubar.png

I want to do with CSS. I thought, I would have to change this code:

```
.nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
        z-index: 5; 
    }
```

I removed left:0, right: 0, gave width 100%. But, it won't work. I can't get the idea what should I do. Please, help me.

Comment: Why don't you just make a vertical dropdown with one line holding all the menu points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a width to the inner UL and float the LI for that inner UL http://jsfiddle.net/eSxT9/1/

```
.nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    width:1000px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 5; 
}
.nav ul ul li {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: inline` for that particular `<ul>`

Heres a simmilar example of the logic http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/te5AU/268/

Comment: Though, I've gotten solusion by verbanicm, Thank you too for your solusion.